# Swapping in mobile systems

Tags: operating-systems

I know that swapping is avoided in mobile systems because of limited memory but I came across this question and couldn't answer if the answer is yes.

Should swapping be done in Mobile systems? If yes, what should be the appropriate swap size in case the secondary storage is 16 times that of RAM. Which swapping location would be best in this case?

Comment: (`swapping is avoided[…]because of limited memory` I remember swapping *introduced* for that very reason.) Is *paging* used (concurrently with swapping) in the `Mobile systems` considered?

Comment: @greybeard From what I have read, swapping is avoided in mobile systems because mobile systems use Flash memory which is small in size and slower in comparison to disks used in computers.

Comment: Maybe you have read old information. "Mobile systems" today are mostly ARM 64 bits and it does support paging which can be used for other things than page swapping but page swapping is useful and is probably used in mobile systems today. There is not 100 ways that a game using 5GB of RAM in a 4GB mobile system will work. It must use page swapping to disk in this case.

Comment: I think [references](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) and/or quotes would be helpful here - and more information on what exactly `swapping` refers to above. As of early 2022, MLC still seems to come with an annoying limit on the number of writes before all bets on data retention are off. Top capacities seem to be at about 16 TB for both MLC SSDs & HHDs, sustained write speeds in the same ball park. SSD still cost a price ante, single digit now. I thought HDDs were urged to include flash caches for energy savings - didn't find reliable information beyond "256 MB cache" - DRAM?